# Groovy: Extracting numbers from file

Tags: groovy

I have a list with lots of numbers like:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
...
```

How can I extract them line by line and do some calculations?
Something like (pseudocode):

```
def f = new File("data.txt")
f.eachLine() {
    println(it.findAll( /\d+/ )*.toInteger()*2)
}
```

I need to get rid of the comma and the whitespaces.

Comment: You're almost there, why did you stop!? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
def fileContent = new File('data.txt').text
def matches = fileContent =~ /\d+/
matches.each {
    println new Integer(it)*2
}
```

Gives

```
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
```

Comment: When I replace those numbers with `new File("data.txt")`, I get an empty output.

Comment: Use -> def fileContent = new File("data.txt").text

Comment: See the comment? Also, are you 100% your file exists in that location. Test this by simply running -> println(new File("data.txt").text) . Sometimes its better to fully qualify the path i.e. new File("c:/test/data.txt")

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
file.splitEachLine(/,\s+/){
        it.each(){
                println it.replace(/,/,'').toInteger() * 2
        }
}
```

If the file didn't have the comma on the end of the line then don't need the replace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Scanner to read all your data from a file. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) is the link

Comment: Thanks but I prefer to use Groovy rather than Java.

Comment: Ah ok. This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360191/groovy-parsing-text-file

Answer (score 0):

Here is one to help. I still believe there could be a better way:

```
def list = []
new File('data.txt').eachLine{
    list << it.replaceAll(/,/, '')
}

assert list*.replaceAll('\\s+', "")*.toInteger() == [12345, 678910]
//or
assert list.collect{it.replaceAll('\\s+', "").toInteger()} == [12345, 678910]
```